# Why aren't questions that belong on Expats migrated there rather than closed?

Tags: discussion, immigration-questions, migration

There are several related meta questions like:

[Is it necessary to migrate questions...](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/282/is-it-necessary-to-migrate-questions-that-are-in-scope-for-travel-but-also-withi)

[Are H-1B and J-1 questions going to be migrated to expats?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/are-h1-b-and-j-1-questions-going-to-be-migrated-to-expats)

[Immigration once again: what makes something an expat question?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1535/immigration-once-again-what-makes-something-an-expat-question)

Recently there are been multiple questions asked on Travel that have been closed with a suggestion in the comments that the OP should ask the question on [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com). If someone feels strongly enough to suggest that, why isn't the question just getting migrated? Or at least, include in the comment that the OP can flag the question and request a moderator migrate it?

If not there already, could there be a customized close reason that would reflect this trend?

Edit/Update: I was reading the recent Meta SE post about [graduation, site closure, etc.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites?cb=1) and realized that one issue could be the general discouragement of migrating questions to a site still in beta, which Expatriates is. The idea is that a question could be lost if the beta site ends up closing. However, the post clearly indicates that no current beta site is in danger of closing.

Comment: Here's the question that prompted this one: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48630/visa-ban-for-the-uk-does-this-also-affect-an-application-for-a-us-spousal-visa

Comment: And a possibly related meta question on [Expats](http://meta.expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/238/cross-posting-from-travel) about cross-posted questions.

Comment: An additional problem is that while we are busy closing the question/explaining the rules, the OP often cross-posts. Ideally, at least for the 'good' ones, we should perhaps flag ***instead*** of closing.

Comment: Many SEs have this issue (closing instead of migrating).

Answer (score 12):

Need to flag them for mods to migrate, unfortunately.  It's not an automated process.  So do vote to close, but also flag it, so that the mod can see and deal with it.

Comment: I'd always assumed that if you selected the 'this would be better on our sister site' close reason that the mods were automatically informed. Probably a good idea if that could generate an auto-flag (or if the majority of close-voters opt for that) or add something to the dialog saying to flag it too. I guess that'd have to be a question on the main meta to change the base code.

Comment: @SpaceDog indeed. It was created as one of the 3 custom close reasons, but it's just text, there's no brains behind it :(

Comment: Yes please! We don't get notifications for "migrate" close votes, so a quick "better at Expats" puts it in the mod queue.

Comment: IIRC, beta sites never are allowed as automatic migration targets (or to have any automatic migration targets).  So until/unless they graduate that (flagging) is the only option.

Comment: @Joe - is Travel SE still in beta?

Comment: @neubert No, but Expats is.

Comment: You can tell by the 'beta' in the headline, and the lack of custom skin. It's usually a sign that a site has been promoted if it gets its own look and feel. Travel graduated around April 2013, IIRC.

Answer (score 11):

Questions closed as "better on Expats.SE" don't get flagged automatically, so it definitely helps to add a quick mod flag to bring it to our attention.

Also, unless I'm *absloutely* wrong and missing something, once a question is closed by the community the only way a mod can migrate a question is to reopen it, and *then* vote to close as a better match for another site.

Comment: Yes, that's the only way to do it. Unfortunately, it takes three whole seconds. :)