# Please migrate this thread to Expats

Tags: discussion, status-completed, immigration-questions, migration

My fault.  I answered in the wrong site.

This thread...

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49992/uk-dependent-visa-refusal-can-i-apply-for-review-in-this-situation

...does not belong on TSE.  A T2, either for primary or dependents, is off topic on TSE. It's about work permits.

The question is fine, the answer is fine, but the whole shebang should be elsewhere.  I'm surprised nobody put it in the queue, but there you go.  If it stays for a long time other T2 applicants may think TSE is the right place.

Please migrate...

Answer (score 2):

I flagged this both for off-topicness as well as for migration. This is IMHO the most efficient way to deal with migration. Posting here on Meta might not be as effective, since users/mods don't automagically know when new meta posts happen. However close flags are sent to review queues and moderation flags are sent directly to moderators, which are the ones who can act upon them and migrate. See this Meta discussion for more information: [Why aren't questions that belong on Expats migrated there rather than closed?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3225/why-arent-questions-that-belong-on-expats-migrated-there-rather-than-closed)